# Can't connect any Arduino to local DB server, i have tried everything i could think of

Tags: mysql, linux, arduino, esp8266

I am struggeling to get a connection to my local MySQL database that is on a LAMP server, i have tried to get a connection with a Arduino WiFi Rev.2, Arduino Yùn Rev.1, a normal Arduino UNO connected to an ESP8266 and even a ESP-32. I have made a user in MySQL that is only allowed to connect from the IP address that the Arduino has, but whatever i try from the client or server side i can't get it to work.

I'm just using a little sketch i made to get a connection from the Arduino UNO WiFi Rev.2 to the server, I am using the MySQL [library](https://github.com/ChuckBell/MySQL_Connector_Arduino) made by [Dr. Charles Bell](https://github.com/ChuckBell). and i have read though his manual for the lib and all but still, it won't work.

Here is my code for the connection:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <WiFiNINA.h>
#include <MySQL_Connection.h>
#include <MySQL_Cursor.h>
#include "arduino_passwds.h"
#include "arduino_usrs.h" 
char ssid[] = SECRET_SSID;        
char pass[] = SECRET_PASS; 
byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress server_addr(127,0,0,1); //I am not using the local IP of the server in the original sketch. 
char user[] = "MyUser";                   // MySQL user login username
char password[] = "MyPasswd";             // MySQL user login password   
int status = WL_IDLE_STATUS;     
WiFiClient client;
MySQL_Connection conn((Client *)&client);
void setup() 
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial)
  {
   ; 
  }
  if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_MODULE) 
  {
    Serial.println("Communication with WiFi module failed!");
    while (true);
  }
  while (status != WL_CONNECTED) 
  {
    Serial.print("Attempting to connect to WPA SSID: ");
    Serial.println(ssid);
    status = WiFi.begin(ssid, pass);
    delay(10000);
  }
  Serial.println("You're connected to the network");
  printCurrentNet();
  printWifiData();
  Serial.println("Connecting to DB...");
  if (conn.connect(server_addr, 3306, user, password))
  {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Success!");
  }
  else 
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to connect to DB");
    conn.close();
  }
}
void loop() 
{
  delay(5000);
}
```

If you need any more info just ask and ill provide.

Comment: You are not trying to connect your server but to device itself - you need to specify IP address of your lamp server

Comment: is the port open on firewall of the server?

Comment: i have the IP to my server in the original sketch, i just hid it in this post. but yes, i have opened the port and made the server listen to the IP address to the arduino on that exact port too.